# Is it possible to use variable name in imread? Basic issue in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy

My problem is really quite simple.

I have a 100 images on my computer, those images are called 1.ppm 2.ppm and so on until 100.ppm

I want to read each image to a variable using imread, and then perform a few operations. I want to do the exact same thing to all of the images.

My question is this - Instead of copy pasting one hundred times, is it possible to use imread in a loop? something like:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    X=io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/more pics/'i'.ppm')
```

Instead of copy pasting the same code block and just changing the picture number a hundred times, I want to do this in a loop.
I have a similar issue with numpy.load. I want to load files called ICA1 ICA2 etc up to ICA100. Is it possible to write something like

`numpy.load('/home/oria/Desktop/ICA DB/ICA'i'.npy)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    X=io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/more pics/%s.ppm' %(i))
```

Or, like this:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    X=io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/more pics/'+str(i)+'.ppm')
```

Go ahead and read the article on [basic string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) as well as this simple article on [string formatting](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)

Comment: I see. Will this work the same way with numpy.load and numpy.save?

Comment: Yes, this is string formatting. Go ahead and read this article: http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html

Comment: The second solution you gave me doesn't work. It says "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

Comment: Strange? I was sure Python did that.. You can wrap the int in str(). I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're asking, it could be done as:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    x = io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/more pics/' + str(i) + '.ppm')
```

Note that the high end of the `range` function is not inclusive, so using `range(1, 100)` would only produce 1, 2, 3...99. Also note that `i` must be converted to a string or you will receive `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import os

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str.format`, passing the variable `i`:

```
for i in range(1,100):
     X = io.imread('/home/oria/Desktop/more pics/{}.ppm'.format(i))
```

When you want to load with numpy do the same thing again:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    X = numpy.load('/home/oria/Desktop/ICA DB/ICA{}.npy'.format(i))
```